# Need to find DOCX to PDF Conversion C# API

Tags: c#, .net

From within C#, I want to be able to take a DOCX file and convert it to PDF.

How can I do this?

The catch is that I would like to do other types too, e.g. images, doc files, etc.

I also ideally would like there to be no office installed on the computer where this software will be running.

Perhaps the answer is to some software that 'prints to pdf'

My software is dealing with arrays of data representing the file, so it would ideally be some kind of API that handles byte arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something free (but requires Microsoft Word to be installed), you could try using Word itself via .NET code:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreatePDFsForFree.aspx

It isn't the solution for everything but it can be useful at times.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't a ton of good C# libraries for this one. It's hard to do without COM.

Here's one option:

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx

Comment: OK, seems to be the case. I would rather have something that is free. But perhaps I might have to go back to looking at a solution that requires office to be installed.

Comment: You could use something like LibreOffice; I think you can call some of the "save as" filters from the command line. Not sure if that's any better than using native office though.

Answer (score 1):

DOCX is Office 2007 format. If you don't mind using the built-in functionality of Office 2007, you might want to check this link out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Office automation + [Save As Pdf Add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1fc413c-6d89-4f15-991b-63b07ba5f2e5&displaylang=en) ?